# R formula - add squares of all variables

Tags: r, regression, formula

How to add squares of all variables to formula :

`lm(output ~ ., data = myData)` # usual formula
`lm(output ~ .^2, data = myData)` # formula with all interactions

We can construct the formula manually with paste :

`xnam <- paste0(names(myData)[-1], "^2")` # output in first column

`xnam <- paste0("I(", xnam, ")^2")` # x' -> 'I(x^2)`

`(fmla <- as.formula(paste("output ~.+", paste(xnam, collapse= "+"))))`
`lm(fmla)`

but could we do the same using `formula` syntax alone ?

Comment: What I would do is to build `myData2=myData^2` and use `myData2` as the matrix with explanatory variables. I don't know if it is possible to make easier.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25975/how-to-add-second-order-terms-into-the-model-in-r